# Unable to call out on VoIP number via gsm getaway mode using GoIP

Tags: voip

The difficulty we are facing in making an outgoing call : when making a call on voip extn No. 302 (for example), we can hear the bell ringing once, thereafter, we hear an engaged tone, and after a time span of 16 seconds, the call gets disconnected.

Comment: Pleas read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.